# Why does RDLC table inner border thicker than outer border

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, rdlc

I am working with WPF RDLC with a table that will display my record ,i was wondering why the inner border is more thicker compare to the outer border

Following is one of the example

[image]

All border I set to 1pt , but the outer look like 1pt , the inner look like 2pt

Is that anyway for me to set it all to border same width ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

- selecting the table itself (not the collection of cells in the
  table) and then set the table's border.
- resize the table so it doesn't touch the report edge.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem and solution .

The problem is because each cell is set to 1pt width for the border , therefore a column consist more than a cell side by side , the border will look thicker .

To solve this borders that look thinker require to reduce the border width to 0.5 , so that when both cell side by side , the total border width will be 1pt

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution if you have already checked border width.

It is possible if the inside columns and rows **border style** is solid but the entire table (select the corner) **border style** is none. Change it so that they are the same.